# Code changes not reflecting in a signed APK, it updates database but code is not updating

Tags: android, sqlite, encryption, build, apk

I have a dictionary app and I've recently updated its database with some custom encryption applied on the database data and published that apk.

Users with the old apk are updated to new one but their database is only updating and there code is still the same one that makes encrypted data visible to user instead of the original one.

But the new users are getting the new database and the latest code as well with decryption working in it.

It is very strange and I don't know why this is happening. Your help is appreciated.

Comment: Try to uninstall APP so new database created.

Comment: How can i ask user to uninstall and install it again, they will uninstall it for ever :D

Comment: if you made changes with database, then you should drop the old one, simply change the database's version in the helper class

Comment: the database is updating as it has to be the issue is the code changes i had made are not reflecting if i update it from the previous version

Answer (score 0):

If you are using sqlite, you can change the version code in the helper's constructor

Then apply what you need to do to the overriding update method